# Xubuntu installed when I was expecting Ubuntu

Tags: installation, xubuntu

Yesterday, I downloaded and installed a Ubuntu 13.04 (using the minimised CD) on a Revo. Everything worked fine, I quited liked it (pretty new to Linux), and I thought I'd add it to my PC as a dual boot with Windows 8.

So, I put the same CD in my PC, ran through the install, selecting exactly the same options (except for the dual boot), but it's different. When I booted (selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu), I was presented with a screen saying `Xbubtu`.

From what I understand it is designed primarily for machines that do not have the recommended specs for Ubuntu, but not only is my PC considerably more powerful than the Revo, I was never offered a choice.

First and foremost, can anyone explain why this would have been installed and not the proper version of Ubuntu? And I'd like to reiterate - until I started booting, Xubuntu had not been mentioned, and and was certainly not asked if I'd like to install that instead.

Next, I wonder how I can safely remove it? I'd like to not have to faff about fixing my MBR, so is there a way to safely remove Xununtu without affecting it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to re-install, drop to a command prompt from xubuntu StartButton?  ---> Accessories ---> Terminal Emulator and enter the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install -y ubuntu-desktop
```

Log out and log in using the ubuntu desktop instead of xubuntu and you are good.

Comment: Gutted - I've just removed it! Will be trying again on Monday, so I'll bare that in mind in case I run in to problems again. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have no clue how you installed that without using the wrong download / cd. Are you sure you did not download Xu onto another cd and pick that one up by accident?

Just re-download Ubuntu, burn it to a cd, hold it in your hand and walk over to the computer, put it in, remove the partition that has the Xu installed, and install Ubuntu over that partition.

Comment: I'd never even heard of Xubuntu, let alone downloaded it and burned it on to a CD. My point above was that I did not know that I had to remove a partition. I'd have thought there would be an uninstall method, that wouldn't damage the MBR, but there was not it seems.

Comment: Oh, FYI - I used the minimised CD install, so all packages were downloaded for install. I thinking that probably had something to do with it, but I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: Quite possibly. Do you have the option of downloading the DVD and burning it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, our work PC's are very old and only have CD drives. I asked if I could buy a DVD super-multi and was told no! I'll figure out a way of getting the full install though...